# How do I open the "Share Menu" preferences on OSX?

Tags: macos, cocoa

Much like Safari, trying to implement a button that when clicked opens System Preferences > Extensions > Share Menu pane.

I have tried:

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preferences.extensions?Share_Menu"];
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:URL];
```

However it seems like that is not working on newer versions, any ideas?

[image: System Preferences Extensions Pane]

Answer (score 1):

You can use Scripting Bridge to do something like this:

```
 SBSystemPreferencesApplication *systemPrefs =
[SBApplication applicationWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.systempreferences"];

[systemPrefs activate];

SBElementArray *panes = [systemPrefs panes];
SBSystemPreferencesPane *notificationsPane = nil;

for (SBSystemPreferencesPane *pane in panes) {
    if ([[pane id] isEqualToString:@"com.apple.preferences.extensions"]) {
        notificationsPane = pane;
        break;
    }

}

[systemPrefs setCurrentPane:notificationsPane];

SBElementArray *anchors = [notificationsPane anchors];

for (SBSystemPreferencesAnchor *anchor in anchors) {
    if ([anchor.name isEqualToString:@"Extensions"]) {
        [anchor reveal];
    }
}
```

Of course you need to add the ScriptingBridge framework to your project and a Scripting Bridge header file for system preferences. More details on how to use Scripting Bridge you can find in the developer documentation from Apple.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Since macOS Ventura (13.0) you can call the URL

`x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preferences.extensions?Sharing`